# How to perform drag and drop inside svg element using selenium?

Tags: selenium, svg

[below is the image of page element,i want to drag and drop inside svg element tried action class and robot class as well but not able to do.

```html
resizeblockTwo']">
<div class="chartCanvas js-resizeblockOne drpm-resize__block-one">
<div class="titleBar layout-align-space-between-center layout-row">
<graph-canvas class="ng-scope">
<section class="chartContainer">
<div class="chartArea joint-theme-default paper" droppable="">
<svg id="v-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
</section>
<div ng-transclude="">
</graph-canvas>
<div class="processflow-empty-message ng-scope" ng-if="emptyGraph" style="">
<div class="drpm-resize__grabber">
</div>
```

Comment: *tried action class and robot class*... Show how you tried

Comment: Actions act=new Actions(fd); //find element which we need to drag WebElement drag=fd.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type=InputData]")); //find element which we need to drop WebElement drop=fd.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg[id='v-2']")); //this will drag element to destination act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform(); code is getting passed but drag and drop is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to cssSelector as selenium has the problem to handle svn tag with other locators. I have experienced the same.

Now pass the same element in selenium drag and drop by action class. You havn't specify the element we can't extract CssSelector for you, you can use `chrome-> Inspect-> copy -> copy selector`

In java it will be something like below :-

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);

// find element which we need to drag
WebElement drag=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("YOUR CSS Selector"))

// find element which we need to drop
WebElement drop=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("YOUR CSS Selector"));

// this will drag element to destination
act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Actions act=new Actions(fd);

//find element which we need to drag
WebElement drag=fd.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type=InputData]"));

//find element which we need to drop
WebElement drop=fd.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg[id='v-2']"));

//this will drag element to destination
act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();   code is getting passed but drag and drop is not happening.